# I am very new in c, and I need some help of arrays

Tags: c, arrays

So basically, I want user to put their family size and depending on their size, I want to ask their ages as many times as family member( so input depends on them).
Now, I want the age input as array listing. for example, if they are 2 of them , then I want to ask their age twice and save it as

```
scanf("%d",age[0]);
scanf(%d",age[1]);
```

Here I could think of c code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    int main(int n, int age[0]){
        printf("enter your family number:");
        scanf("%d", n);
    }

    for(i=1; i>=n; i++){
        printf("Can I have your family's age one by one:");
        scanf("%d",&age[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You told us what you want to happen, now what is your question/problem?

Comment: I advise you to read a basic tutorial my friend.

Comment: Array sizes should be known at compile-time unless you're using C99s VLAs. You can go with dynamically allocated arrays however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n;
    printf("enter your family number:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int i, age[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        printf("Can I have your family's age one by one:");
        scanf("%d", &age[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: think you very much, you opened my eyes. Now I feel more confident